# How to run Spring Reactive integration tests using EmbeddedPostgres

Tags: java, spring, reactive, embedded-postgres

I created a Spring reactive based Controller/repository and use r2dbc-postgresql driver.

Previously, for testing classical Spring boot REST service I use EmbeddedPostgres. I tried to add the same for the reactive based controller but instead of embedded postgres it tries to connect to the normal local PostgreSQL DB.

Looks like async PostgreSQL driver is not compatible with embedded.

Is there any way to let them work together in my integration tests?

Comment: were you able to find a solution for this?